# Does storing a Bag of Holding in a Glove of Storing activate the tear in the astral plane?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items

Does storing a [Bag of Holding](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/a-b/bag-of-holding/) in a [Glove of Storing](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/e-g/glove-of-storing/) activate the tear in the astral plane? And is there a difference between a Glove of Storing and a [Pathfinders Pouch](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/m-p/pathfinder-pouch/)?

Answer (score 4):

### You can put one inside the other safely.

Only *Bags of Holding* and *Portable Holes* interact in a way that causes a rift into the *Astral Plane*. All other items that create extradimensional spaces simply cease to function and become inaccessible when placed inside another such item or space (such as the space created by the spell *Rope Trick*)

> A number of spells and magic items utilize extradimensional spaces, such as rope trick, a bag of holding, a handy haversack, and a portable hole. [...] **Such items do not function, however, inside another extradimensional space. If placed inside such a space, they cease to function until removed from the extradimensional space.** For example, if a bag of holding is brought into a rope trick, the contents of the bag of holding become inaccessible until the bag of holding is taken outside the rope trick. **The only exception to this is when a bag of holding and a portable hole interact** [...]

### There is a difference between a *Glove of Storing* and a *Pathfinder Pouch*

The *Pathfinder Pouch* makes a rather small extradimensional space that can be used to store a handful of items, and does not detect as magical, nor can any items contained within be detected. A *Glove of Storing*, on the other hand [HA], does not actually store an item in an extradimensional space, it merely shrinks a single item to become to small to be seen, and attaches it to the palm of the glove. It also does not have any protection against being detected as magical, nor does it provide any protection of that sort to an item it is storing. Theoretically, you could put on a *Glove of Storing* store some sort of item in it, like a greatsword or a crossbow, and then remove the glove and place it inside a *Pathfinder Pouch* in order to smuggle something larger than the pouch would normally allow somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

From the Bag of Holding description:

> If a bag of holding is placed within a portable hole, a rift to the Astral Plane is torn in the space: bag and hole alike are sucked into the void and forever lost.

Looking at the description of the Glove of Storing it says it shrinks the item down, rather than shifting it into another dimension.

> The item is shrunk down so small within the palm of the glove that it cannot be seen.

As for the Glove of Storing vs Pathfinders Pouch, the Glove stores a single object, up to 20lb and requires a free hand, the Pouch stores any number of items, up to 10lb and just takes up space on a belt.

Comment: Is that a "no", then?

Comment: Reading the linked description of the Glove of Storing, it looks like indeed you can safely drop a Bag of Holding into the Glove of Storing. I wonder if this means you could then put the Glove of Storing into a second Bag of Holding without creating a rift to the Astral Plane, since the Glove of Storing has established a "barrier" of sorts between the two Bags of Holding?

Comment: @RobertF It wouldn't do anything, as a *Bag of Holding* only tears a rift if it is placed within a *Portable Hole*. That being said, the *Glove of Storing* specifically states that it does not suppress the effects of any item stored within, so if you stored a *Bag of Holding* in a *Glove of Storing* then tossed it into a *Portable Hole* it would tear a rift open.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.